# Python: "while" is too slow, and sleep(0.25) becomes sleep(3) in actual execution

Tags: python, runtime, raspberry-pi3

I am running a Python Program on a Raspberry Pi 3 which I want to log the temperature from a DS18B20 sensor once every 0.25 seconds.

Earlier, when the program was simple and displaying the temperature on shell, it was quite fast and not having issues. Unfortunately due to the program itself now which includes logging to a file, I am getting a log every 2 seconds or 3 seconds only.

How do I ensure the 0.25 second logging interval.

I have shared the code below:

```
#This program logs temperature from DS18B20 and records it
#Plots the temperature-time plot.

import os
import sys
#import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from re import findall
from time import sleep, strftime, time
from datetime import *

#plt.ion()
#x = []
#y = []

ds18b20 = ''

def setup():
    global ds18b20
    for i in os.listdir('/sys/bus/w1/devices'):
        if i != 'w1_bus_master1':
            ds18b20 = i

# Reads temperature data from the Temp sensor
# This needs to be modified for use with max31855 and K-type thermocouples
def read():
#   global ds18b20
    location = '/sys/bus/w1/devices/' + ds18b20 + '/w1_slave'
    tfile = open(location)
    text = tfile.read()
    tfile.close()
    secondline = text.split("\n")[1]
    temperaturedata = secondline.split(" ")[9]
    temperature = float(temperaturedata[2:])
    temperature = temperature / 1000
    return temperature

#Loop for logging - sleep, and interrupt to be configured.
def loop():
        while True:
                if read() != None:
                        print "Current temperature : %0.3f C" % read()
                        #sleep(0.25)
                        func()

def write_temp(temperature,file_name):
        with open(file_name, 'a') as log:
                log.write("{0},{1}\n".format(datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S"),str(temperature)))

arg = sys.argv[1]
filename1 = str(arg) + "-" + datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y-%H-%M-%S")+".csv"

def func():
        temperature = read()
        #sleep(0.25)
        write_temp(temperature,filename1)
        #graph(temperature)

#For plotting graph using MatPlotLib
#Comment out this function during foundry trials to avoid system slowdown
#Check system resource usage and slowdown using TOP or HTOP

#def graph(temperature):
#        y.append(temperature)
#        x.append(time())
#        plt.clf()
#        plt.scatter(x,y)
#        plt.plot(x,y)
#        plt.draw()              

#Interrupt from command-line
def destroy():
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        setup()
        func()
        loop()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        destroy()
```

I have commented out sections that I thought to be resource heavy, but still I can't manage anything less than 2 seconds. I am getting results as below:

**Output:**

```
27-09-2016 12:18:41,23.0
27-09-2016 12:18:43,23.062
27-09-2016 12:18:46,23.125
27-09-2016 12:18:48,23.187
27-09-2016 12:18:50,23.187
27-09-2016 12:18:53,23.562
27-09-2016 12:18:55,25.875
27-09-2016 12:18:58,27.187
27-09-2016 12:19:00,27.5
```

Comment: You are reading the temperature from your sensor **three times** before actually writing the first line. However, probably the write operation is the most time-consuming part.

Comment: You are opening the log file every time you do a write.  Try to open the file just once and reuse it.

Comment: Every call to write_temp opens the file, writes and closes it again. If you put the "with open(file_name, 'a') as log:" outside the loop in loop in loop you could save a lot of load. Also, consider running two programs. One lightweight one to read the temp and log it. Then run a second to open the log in read only mode to do your processing and graphing. One final thing, I didn't think the DS18B20 updated more frequently than every second - but I could easily be mistasken. HTH

Comment: If you want exact(ish) intervals, look into [`signal.setitimer()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html#signal.setitimer) using `signal.ITIMER_REAL`. As previous comments have suggested, have a very light weight procedure bound to *SIGALRM* that reads the sensor value and just dumps it for later processing.

Comment: @R-Sharp,

Thanks for your input. I will look into it. I will remove graphing for now to relieve some load. And regarding the DS18B20, it has 4 update rates based on bit conv (93 ms to 750 ms)., and I will work on configuring that next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Only open the logfile once (and close it on program exit)
2. Don't always re-read the temperature from the sensor. You call `read()` way too often.
3. Reduce general overhead and simplify your calls.

I am not able to completely test this, but something like this sould work:

```
import os
import sys
import time
from datetime import datetime

def read_temp(dev):
    '''Reads temperature from sensor and returns it as float.'''
    loc = '/sys/bus/w1/devices/' + dev + '/w1_slave'
    with open(loc) as tf:
        return float(tf.read().split('\n')[1].split(' ')[9][2:]) / 1000.0

def write_temp(t, logfile):
    '''Writes temperature as .3 float to open file handle.'''
    logfile.write('{0},{1:.3f}\n'.format(datetime.now().strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S'), t))

def loop(dev, logfile):
    '''Starts temperature logging until user interrupts.'''
    while True:
        t = read_temp(dev)
        if t:
            write_temp(t, logfile)
            print('Current temperature: {0:.3f} °C'.format(t))
            sys.stdout.flush() # Flush. Btw, print is time-consuming!
            time.sleep(.25)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Take the first match for a device that is not 'w1_bus_master1'
    dev = [d for d in os.listdir('/sys/bus/w1/devices') if d != 'w1_bus_master1'][0]
    # Prepare the log filename
    fname = str(sys.argv[1]) + "-" + datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y-%H-%M-%S")+".csv"
    # Immediately open the log in append mode and do not close it!
    logfile = open(fname, 'a')

    try:
        # Only pass device and file handle, not the file name.
        loop(dev, logfile)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        # Close log file on exit
        logfile.close()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time and effort to suggest a solution for this. I have a Raspberry Pi 3 with me, so I will run it and give you a feedback on your suggestion.

Comment: Getting the following error while running:

sudo python TTL001.py LOG
  File "TTL001.py", line 27
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc2' in file TTL001.py on line 27, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details

Comment: Add ``# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`` at the top of your file (as described in the linked PEP) and save the file in ``utf-8``-encoding. Or remove the ``°`` char in the ``print()`` call in my script, which is the non-ASCII character.

Comment: Added that, but now I am getting the following:

sudo python TTL002.py LOG
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TTL002.py", line 42, in <module>
    loop(dev, logfile)
  File "TTL002.py", line 27, in loop
    write_temp(t, logfile)
  File "TTL002.py", line 20, in write_temp
    logfile.write('{},{0:.3f}\n'.format(datetime.now().strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S'), t))
ValueError: cannot switch from automatic field numbering to manual field specification

I tried to change it to logfile.write('{1},{2},{0:.3f}\n', but that is also not correct

Comment: You are a genius. That solved the issue. Now it logs at 1 per 750 ms at the standard rate for the DS18B20 (like @R.Sharp) mentioned. Now i will change the conversion to get a faster update rate from the sensor. Thanks a million for your input. Also, your geospin website/service i noticed, is excellent, and has a lot of possibilities. Cheers to you.